# What is the method to save objects in a compressed form using multiple threads/cores in R?

Tags: r, multithreading, bash, compression

There are a number of compression protocols that support multiple core/thread compression/decompression.  However, it appears the base decompression/compression methods all use a single core (even though at least of the algorithms support multiple cores).

If there isn't an existing tool to accomplish this, is there a way to manage it without dropping out to Java or C?

I thought that I could use the ability to `pipe` or `serialize` to get what I wanted by passing the R object out to the shell/command-line somehow.  But, I can't seem to get a usable form of the object out of R that way (maybe I'm missing something?).  The 'obvious' solution would be use `dput` but the note in the help for that function makes it pretty clear that using `dput` to turn an R object into ASCII for the sake of saving isn't a suitable (or safe) purpose for `dput`.  The alternative mentioned `dump` acts like `save` (I'd rather have something like `saveRDS`), and still routes the file to a `.Internal` that is impenetrable without digging into R's C code.

What other approaches to solve this problem should I consider?

Comment: There is a section in ?save titled '[Parallel compression](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/save.html)' in recent versions of R. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yeah that looks like it might work. I'll report back. Looks like I was constructing the pipe incorrectly.

Comment: I was going to suggest pigz, but there it is already at @MartinMorgan's link.

Answer (score 5):

With the resource provided by @Martin I wrote the following code.

## xz

For compression, I wanted to try first with xz.  However, the version of xz packaged on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as of the moment (5.1.0alpha) does not support parallel compress.  So, I use pxz instead.

```
saveRDS.xz <- function(object,file,threads=parallel::detectCores()) {
  con <- pipe(paste0("pxz -T",threads," > ",file),"wb")
  saveRDS(object, file = con, compress=FALSE)
  close(con)
}
```

The companion code readRDS.xz code also works for any regular RDS files **saved using xz compression**.  Also note that, although pxz does not decompress in parallel, there are time savings (about 1/3rd saved on my system) associated with using this code.  This is because decompression moves to another thread and the R thread is left to process the incoming stream.  On my system, R's single-threaded CPU usage maxes out well before pxz's does.

```
readRDS.xz <- function(file,threads=parallel::detectCores()) {
  con <- pipe(paste0("pxz -d -k -c -T",threads," ",file))
  object <- readRDS(file = con)
  close(con)
  return(object)
}
```

## pigz

Alternatively we can use pigz (gz) to compress and decompress.

saveRDS.gz <- function(object,file,threads=parallel::detectCores()) {
  con <- pipe(paste0("pigz -p",threads," > ",file),"wb")
  saveRDS(object, file = con)
  close(con)
}

The decompression in pigz is not entirely multi-threaded.  But as with xz there is a speed benefit to taking the decompression off R's thread.  On my system both pxz and pigz provide similar decompression times (perhaps due to the bottleneck in R mentioned in the above section).

```
saveRDS.gz <- function(object,file,threads=parallel::detectCores()) {
  con <- pipe(paste0("pigz -p",threads," > ",file),"wb")
  saveRDS(object, file = con)
  close(con)
}

readRDS.gz <- function(file,threads=parallel::detectCores()) {
  con <- pipe(paste0("pigz -d -c -p",threads," ",file))
  object <- readRDS(file = con)
  close(con)
  return(object)
}
```

## bzip2

Provided me performance somewhere between the other two, and so I skip it here.

## Together

With those functions established we can write a quick wrapper such that it does the right thing.

```
readRDS.p <- function(file,threads=parallel::detectCores()) {
  #Hypothetically we could use initial bytes to determine file format, but here we use the Linux command file because the readBin implementation was not immediately obvious
  fileDetails <- system2("file",args=file,stdout=TRUE)
  selector <- sapply(c("gzip","XZ"),function (x) {grepl(x,fileDetails)})
  format <- names(selector)[selector]
  if (format == "gz") {
    object <- readRDS.gz(file, threads=threads)
  } else if (format == "XZ") {
    object <- readRDS.xz(file, threads=threads)
  } else {
    object <- readRDS(file)
  }
  return(object)
}
```